# Selecting Records depending on two IDs

Tags: php, laravel

This is kinda complicated, but  whatever..
Okay I have four Tables

```
1-Projects 

 id     | int 11
 name 
2-Sections

 id         | int 11
 project_id | int 11
 name
3-Users

 id         | int 11

4-User_Section_project (this table is used to assign users to sections they will work on in the project

id         | int 11
project_id | int 11
section_id | int 11
user_id    | int 11
```

Is there anyway using ORM to make something like that works and I get only the assigned sections

```
$sections = $user->projects()->sections()
```

I made it out using the following code in my User model

```
 public function workshops()
{


    return $this->belongsToMany('section', 'user_project_section', 'user_id', 'section_id')->whereIn('user_project_section.project_id', array(1,2,3));
}
```

And I call it like that

```
@foreach ( $user->sections as $section)
                    {{$section->name}}

                @endforeach
```

This code will get the associated Sections for the users in Projects 1,2,3. 
If i want to make it for a specified project, I pass a parameter the problem is when adding parentheses ()  to the call of the function in the view it doesn't work so I can't pass a parameter

```
@foreach ( $user->sections() as $section)
                    {{$section->name}}

                @endforeach
```

What makes it worse there is no error msg pops up and monitoring my Mysql Server Queries , This is not queried (executed) at all.
I really Need that to pass a parameter
More Info : 
Using Print_r it appears that without () it returns Collection Object , with-it it returns BelongsToMany Object.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes. Is someone going to actually write up all the code for you and put it here? probably not. If you are interested in using ORM, I'm sure that are a few good quality ones out there with documentation you can read and use.

An ORM is nothing more than an object oriented approach to dealing with databases. Instead of treating tables like tables, you treat a table like an object and so act on them as such, lending the power of code reuse and code interplay. However, a trade off of using ORM is generally the overhead. That is why many small projects don't use it - too much for what they need.

Comment: I already know that and I use Eloquent,I just was wondering if anyone going to provides some hints .
Any way I made it out